# preg_match and new line symbol

Tags: php, regex, multiline

I have the following string

```
№ покупки(OrderId) : 12345
Доп.Информация 1 : Имя
Доп.Информация 2 : Уставная деятельность
```

I want to catch line which starts with `Доп.Информация 1`.

This one works:

```
Доп\.Информация 1\W*:\W*(\w*)
```

This one doesn't:

```
^Доп\.Информация 1\W*:\W*(\w*)$
```

Only this one works:

```
^№
```

What's wrong? As far as I know the `^` symbol is used not only for search at the start of the string itself but also after `\n` symbols.

Comment: Only in multiline mode it marks the start of the string and of any line (which is also the start of the string). By default this is *not* the case, you need the multiline modifier for that: [`m (PCRE_MULTILINE)`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you use multiline mode. You can activate it like this:

```
'/^Доп\.Информация 1\W*:\W*(\w*)$/m'
```

Just put it after your delimiter (whichever character you are using for it). [This part](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) of the documentation shows how to use these modifiers.

Alternatively it is possible to set these options inside the regex and even just for individual parts of it (although this is probably not needed in your case). Here is how it would work:

```
'/(?m:^Доп\.Информация 1\W*:\W*(\w*)$)/'
```

Or you can set the modifier from a certain point onward like this:

```
'/(?m)^Доп\.Информация 1\W*:\W*(\w*)$/'
```

For this style, check out [this bit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.internal-options.php) of the documentation.

Comment: You are using a modifier in your code example, not the internal option you linked. Just saying, you could show both ways how to do it. Albeit it's likely for the OP that it's more about the modifier for the whole pattern, not for only a part the internal options could be used for.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I didn't even know about this mode. But `^Доп\.Информация 1\W*:\W*(\w*)$` doesn't work too, it works only if I add `\W*` between the catch group and `$` symbol. Why? `$` matches only `\n`, not `\r\n`?

Comment: @efpies yes that might be the reason. the documentation doesn't explicitly state it, but it says "If there are no `\n` characters in a subject string [...] setting this modifier has no effect." so I guess only `\n` is considered for line-endings. I would also suggest that you use `\s` (whitespace character)  instead of `\W` (non-word character)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use multiline mode `/m`, so `^` and `$` will apply for each line of text.

```
/^.* 1 : .*$/m
```

---

Other alternative is:

```
/(?:^|(?<=\n)).* 1 : .*/
```

where `(?:^|(?<=\n))` match beginning of line.